# $ (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R, \leq_{lex}) \cong (\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q, \leq_{lex}) $ - order preserving isomorphism between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$ (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R, \leq_{lex}) \cong (\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q, \leq_{lex}) $

My solution:

$(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R, \leq_{lex}):= \left\{\cdots (-2,-99) \cdots (-1,-99) \cdots (0,-99) \cdots \right\}$

$(\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q, \leq_{lex}):= \left\{ \cdots (-2,\frac{99}{2}) \cdots (-1,-99) \cdots (0,-99) \cdots \right\}$

There is not max,min element , between each 2 elements there are infinite elements.

Is there Isomorphism between 2 sets ? and how i suppose to prove it , i must find specific isomorphism ?

Comment: Hint: consider the statement "For all $x, y$, if $x < y$ then $\{z \mid x < z < y\}$ is uncountable$\}$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ordered set $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb Q, \leq_{lex})$, there are only countably many elements between $(0, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$: they are $\{(0, x): x \in \Bbb Q, 0 < x < 1\}$

However, for any two different elements in the ordered set $(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R, \leq_{lex})$, there are uncountably many elements between them.

This shows that there is no isomorphism between these two ordered sets.